# change label by radio selection

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have these HTML Snippet :

```
<table class="form" style="display: none">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" value="hagh" checked="checked" name="reg">حقیقی</input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" value="hogh" name="reg">حقوقی</input>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>
        <label id="lblregName">نام</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="regname" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <label id="lblregLsatNameEcoCode">نام خانوادگی</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="regLsatNameEcoCode" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <label id="lblregNatCodeRegNo">کد ملی</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="regNatCodeRegNo" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <label id="lblDepName">نام نماینده</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="regDepName" disabled="disabled" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            تلفن همراه
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="regMobile" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            کد
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="regCityCode" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            تلفن ثابت
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="regPhoneNo" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="orange">
                ورود</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to change label caption when user change the radio selection. I was confused in how to get selected radio when user click them and how to change label text. Is it true to access label as $('#labelname').val(sometext)?

Comment: @undefined you know input is a self-closing tag right? the "/>" does that

Comment: @Robuust Yes, I know, what about you? do you know that this markup is invalid?                 `<input type="radio" value="hagh" checked="checked" name="reg">حقیقی</input>`

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippets :

```
$(function(){
    $("input:radio").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $('#labelname').val(sometext);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the appropriate label using traversal methods or by getting the name from the radio and using that to create ID selector for label.

I prefer traverse as it is less tedious to write

```
$(function(){
    $("td input:radio").change(function(){
       var labeltext = this.checked ? 'checked text' : 'unchecked text';
       $(this).parent().prev().find('label').text( labeltext);

    });
});
```